# unable to decode json response into struct

Tags: go

```
➜ curl -H 'Authorization: GenieKey KEY' https://api.opsgenie.com/v2/heartbeats/NAME/ping

{"result":"PONG - Heartbeat received","took":0.009,"requestId":"75fb5c6a-2b74-4298-a51c-384a56bcc193"}
```

this is my go code

```golang
type OpsGenieResponse struct {
    Result    string  `json:"result"`
    Took      float64 `json:"took"`
    RequestID string  `json:"requestId"`
}

req, _ := http.NewRequest(
        http.MethodGet,
        "https://api.opsgenie.com/v2/heartbeats/NAME/ping", 
        nil,
    )
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "GenieKey KEY")

    api := &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 10,
    }
    resp, err := api.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var data OpsGenieResponse
    d := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
    d.Decode(&data)
    fmt.Println(data)
    fmt.Println("Heartbeat is ON")
```

And I always get this:

```
{ 0.001 c40e629c-f40a-48d7-ba9e-49d15520af11}
Heartbeat is ON
```

so I'm unable to get the key "result" mapped to OpsGenieResponse.Result.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: The code works as expected with the JSON response shown in the question.  https://go.dev/play/p/-IEokMdIoM9

Comment: Unrelated reminder, dont forget to close the response body.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an error struct response and check the HTTP status code response, than you decode the right one (error or result).

Your error test, check only if we haven't communication problems with the HTTP server.

E.g.: When status code is `401` we have this JSON response, and the response message doesn't match the `OpsGenieResponse` struct

```
{"message":"Could not authenticate","took":0.0,"requestId":"8389eef8-aed2-477c-b27d-df688de80021"}
```

How to check:

```
    // Check if the HTTP response status code is not 200
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
       ...
       data = myErrorStruct{}
       ...
    }
```